# Best Way to Share Nginx Configuration in Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

[image]

I have 2 ec2 instance with auto scaling group in different AZ. And each instance serve web server using Nginx.

I want change root directory for my server, like this

`root /usr/share/nginx/html/public/`

My question is, how i can edit all instance? is i need EFS for sharing nginx configuration?? or is there another way? or this can be solve with user data??

I want to configure the nginx config at one time in auto scaling group

Answer (score 0):

The proper where is to update your launch template or launch configuration to use the new settings for the nginx. Either through user-data, or through a custom AMI with properly set nginx.